# Graphdat NodeJS - Connection failed ENOENT

Tags: node.js, performance, web-applications, amazon-ec2, monitoring

I tried using Graphdat NodeJS module to monitor my we app but I'm encountering a problem.

My server is running in a Amazon EC2 instance, Ubuntu 12.10 x64.

When I start my node app it prints

```
Graphdat Info: Graphdat (v0.4.6) is enabled
Graphdat Info: Will send to agent on /tmp/gd.agent.sock
```

But as soon as I load the page in the browser it prints

```
Graphdat Error: gd.agent.sync: connection failed (/tmp/gd.agent.sock):  { [Error: connect ENOENT] code: 'ENOENT', errno: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'connect' }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. The script provided to install the logger was not successfully installed and it wasn't running.

```
curl -s -d '{"token":"api.xxxxxxxx"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://dashboard.graphdat.com/agent/install | sh
```